# Text wrap option - suggestion

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I am using this condition only for "JUMP_OBJECT_TEXT_WRAP"

```
if ((mypageDiff != 0) && (myTextWrap.textWrapPreferences.textWrapMode = TextWrapModes.JUMP_OBJECT_TEXT_WRAP))
```

but its alpplied for--TextWrapModes.BOUNDING_BOX_TEXT_WRAP also how can we control it?

by
has

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `==` as  comparison operator like following:

```
if ((mypageDiff != 0) && (myTextWrap.textWrapPreferences.textWrapMode == TextWrapModes.JUMP_OBJECT_TEXT_WRAP))
----------------------------------------------------------------------^^---------
```